Cubic: "An unexpected TLS packet was received" when installing the cubic-wizard PPA repository behind corporate proxy
I'm trying to install the "Cubic" utility on my Ubuntu 22.04 system (a virtual machine on ESXi 7.0).
The system is behind my company's proxy server and I have created the file /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99proxy with the appropriate proxy information:
Acquire::http::Proxy  "http://proxy.mycompany.com:8080";
Acquire::https::Proxy "https://proxy.mycompany.com:8080";
Acquire::ftp::Proxy   "http://proxy.mycompany.com:8080";

I have also added the environment variables to my .bashrc file:
https_proxy=https://proxy.mycompany.com:8080/
HTTPS_PROXY=https://proxy.mycompany.com:8080/
http_proxy=http://proxy.mycompany.com:8080/
HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.mycompany.com:8080/
ftp_proxy=http://proxy.mycompany.com:8080/
FTP_PROXY=http://proxy.mycompany.com:8080/

There is no firewall implemented.
This works fine for any of the sudo apt upgrade commands I have used but when I attempt to add the PPA like so (I've tried both of these) :
sudo -E apt-add-repository -P ppa:cubic-wizard/release
sudo -E apt-add-repository ppa:cubic-wizard/release

I get the following responses:
*maintenance@TC-test:~$ sudo -E apt-add-repository -P ppa:cubic-wizard/release
Repository: 'deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/cubic-wizard/release/ubuntu/ jammy main'
Description:
PPA for Cubic release branch
      ///////
     ///\   \
    ///  \___\  Custom Ubuntu ISO Creator
    \ \  /////
     \ \/////
      \_____\
Cubic (Custom Ubuntu ISO Creator) is a GUI wizard to create a customized Ubuntu or Debian Live ISO image.
Website:   https://github.com/PJ-Singh-001/Cubic/wiki
More info: https://launchpad.net/~cubic-wizard/+archive/ubuntu/release
Adding repository.
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel.
Found existing deb entry in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cubic-wizard-ubuntu-release-jammy.list
Adding deb entry to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cubic-wizard-ubuntu-release-jammy.list
Found existing deb-src entry in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cubic-wizard-ubuntu-release-jammy.list
Adding disabled deb-src entry to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cubic-wizard-ubuntu-release-jammy.list
Adding key to /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/cubic-wizard-ubuntu-release.gpg with fingerprint B7579F80E494ED3406A59DF9081525E2B4F1283B
Ign:1 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/cubic-wizard/release/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Hit:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Ign:1 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/cubic-wizard/release/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:1 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/cubic-wizard/release/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Err:1 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/cubic-wizard/release/ubuntu jammy InRelease
  Could not handshake: An unexpected TLS packet was received. [IP: 56.224.65.80 8080]
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/cubic-wizard/release/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease  Could not handshake: An unexpected TLS packet was received. [IP: 56.224.65.80 8080]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.*

It's the unexpected TLS error that has me confounded.
Other questions concerning this TLS error that I have seen don't provide a solution.
Am I missing something?

You should be checking with your company IT team if their firewall is blocking it.

Voting to close as OP's answer shows the problem was a typo

I solved this issue and it was due to my rush to find a solution and my poor eyesight.
I had entered this into the 99proxy file:
Acquire::https::Proxy "https://proxy.mycompany.com:8080";

and it should have been this:
Acquire::https::Proxy "http://proxy.mycompany.com:8080";

